# Recorrer un objeto de js y split

Tags: javascript, objeto

hola estoy tratando de recorrer un objeto para imprimirlo en una tabla , pero estoy teniendo problemas , esto es lo que estoy tratando de hacer:

```
 console.log(fullBill);
            for(obj in fullBill){
                //console.log(obj.val())
                var arrayN = obj.split('$');
                var str = `
                <tr class="table-light">
                
                    <td class="d-none"></td>
                    <td>${arrayN[0]}</td>
                    <td>$ ${arrayN[1]} .00 </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger float-right" value="x" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                `;
                $('#addToTableDiv').append(str);
               }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podria decirme que estoy haciendo mal? trate de usar un foreach pero encontre que no era la mejor forma, solo que como ven no puedo acceder al texto y separarlo como quiero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj` en este caso, usado en `for()` es un indice o nombre de propiedad obtenido de `fullBill`, no el elemento en si (en este caso, seria `0`, `1`, etc).

Debes usar este indice para obtener el objeto a procesar

```
         for(index in fullBill){
            var obj= fullBill[index];
            var arrayN = obj.split('$');
            var str = `
            <tr class="table-light">
            
                <td class="d-none"></td>
                <td>${index}</td>
                <td>$ ${arrayN[1]} .00 </td>
                <td>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger float-right" value="x" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            `;
            $('#addToTableDiv').append(str);
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás haciendo referencia a la *key* y no al objeto, solo debes cambiar esa línea.

```
console.log(fullBill);
            for(obj in fullBill){
                //console.log(obj.val())
                ////////////////////////////////

                var arrayN = fullBill[obj].split('$');

                ////////////////////////////////
                var str = `
                <tr class="table-light">
                
                    <td class="d-none"></td>
                    <td>${arrayN[0]}</td>
                    <td>$ ${arrayN[1]} .00 </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger float-right" value="x" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                `;
                $('#addToTableDiv').append(str);
               }
```